# Want to neglect repetition of rows which is common in both tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have tables as:-

Table 1: attendance_date

```
 date_id(primary key)     Date
        151                2015-12-01
        152                2015-01-04
        153                2015-02-03
```

Table 2: activities

```
activity_id(primary key)   activity
    1                      Tape laying
    2                      Embossing
    3                      Courier Packing
    4                      Thermal
```

Table 3: employee_details

```
   emp_code(primary key) emp_name
    18                     Varsha
    19                     anand
    20                     mayuri
    21                     john
```

Table 4: emp_time_tracking

```
 # emp_code(foreign key), in_time,       out_time,      date_id(foreign key)
    18,                       09:00:00,     18:00:00.0000, 151
    18,                       18:00:00,     19:30:00.0000, 151
    18,                       18:00:00,     19:30:00.0000, 151
    18,                       09:00:00,     18:00:00.0000, 151
```

Table 5: card_type

```
card_id(primary key)   card_type
    1                   Barcoding
    2                   Big Ribbon
    3                   Biman All
```

Table 6: actual_details

```
 # emp_code, date_id, card_id, wo, activity_id, quty, wastage, mcusage,  
       18         151      1            1           600   0         0
       18         151      2            1           1200  0         0
       18,        151      2            2           300   0         0
       18,        151    3              1           42    0         0
```

By writing the query I want the result like:

```
 emp_code,   Date,    in_time,  out_time,   card_type, activity, quty, wastage, mcusage
    18   2015-12-01  09:00:00, 18:00:00.0000, Barcoding,  Tape laying,600, 0, 0
    18   2015-12-01  18:00:00, 19:30:00.0000  Big Ribbon, Tape laying,1200, 0, 0
    18   2015-12-01  18:00:00, 19:30:00.0000, Big Ribbon, Embossing,300, 0, 0
    18   2015-12-01  09:00:00, 18:00:00.0000, Biman All, Tape laying,42, 0, 0
```

When I am trying to execute the following query:-

```
select i.*,d.Date,t.in_time,t.out_time,c.cardtype,a.wo,v.activity,a.quty,a.wastage,a.mcusage 
from employee_details i 
inner join actual_alldetails a on i.emp_code=a.emp_code 
inner join emp_time_tracking t on t.emp_code=i.emp_code 
inner join attendance_date d on d.date_id=a.date_id  
inner join card_type c on c.card_id=a.card_id 
inner join activities v on v.activity_id=a.activity_id 
where d.Date='2015-12-01' and i.emp_name='Varsha';
```

the query returns repeated rows which is not right answer.

That's why am writing the two query like this:-

```
select a.emp_code, d.Date,c.cardtype, v.activity 
from  employee_details i 
inner join actual_alldetails a on i.emp_code=a.emp_code 
inner join attendance_date d on d.date_id=a.date_id 
inner join card_type c on c.card_id=a.card_id 
inner join activities v on v.activity_id=a.activity_id 
where d.Date='2015-12-01' and i.emp_name='Varsha';
```

and 2nd query like this:

```
select t.emp_code,t.in_time,t.out_time,d.Date 
from employee_details i 
inner join emp_time_tracking t on i.emp_code=t.emp_code 
inner join attendance_date d on d.date_id=t.date_id 
where d.Date='2015-12-01' and i.emp_name='Varsha';
```

Now i want to combine this query to get actual result without the repeated rows.

Comment: "This query will return number of rows which is not right answer." can you be more specific? what exactly does your first query return that you don't like?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [DISTINCT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html) to eliminate duplicates:

```
select distinct  i.*,d.Date,t.in_time,t.out_time,c.cardtype,a.wo,v.activity,a.quty,a.wastage,a.mcusage 
from employee_details i 
inner join actual_alldetails a on i.emp_code=a.emp_code 
inner join emp_time_tracking t on t.emp_code=i.emp_code 
inner join attendance_date d on d.date_id=a.date_id  
inner join card_type c on c.card_id=a.card_id 
inner join activities v on v.activity_id=a.activity_id 
where d.Date='2015-12-01' and i.emp_name='Varsha';
```

Comment: Did this answer your question? If yes, consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark next to it.